# Retrieve ID from recently created table in Laravel

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I have the tables `item` and `item_actions`.

The relation is something like this:

```
Schema::create('item', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->timestamps();
        });

Schema::create('item_action', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->foreign('itemid')->references('id')->on('item')->onDelete('cascade');
 });
```

Now I want to create a new "item_action" every time I create an "item".

```
$item = new item();
$item->save();

$item_action = new item_action();
$item_action->itemid = DB::table('item')->latest()->first();
$item_action->save();
```

This works but I am afraid it will eventually fail if some people try to use it at the same time.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this:

```
$item = new item();
$item->save();
$id = $item->id;
```